# How do you create a browser profile for Selenium's PhantomJS/GhostDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

Here's how you create a Firefox profile:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")
```

How do you do it with PhantomJS (GhostDriver)?

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't support automatic downloading, so there is no such "profile" that would make sense.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can get with phantomjs is to use the driver capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
caps.setCapability( "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla");
Set<String> cliArgs = new HashSet<>();
cliArgs.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
cliArgs.add("--ssl-protocol=any");
cliArgs.add("--web-security=false");
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgs);
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

However, you notice that there are no configuration options for automatic downloading, since phantomjs does not support this. It is anyway not a very good idea to use selenium for testing of downloads. I did [answer another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992957/download-file-dialog/17993357#17993357) earlier in which I point to [an article about this](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) and why you should not do it.